# Android displaying a crisp image after zooming

Tags: android, image

Currently I have a set of images which has resolution of 480x640 each.

When I zoom the image using an image displayer library I got from googling (TouchImageView), the image got a bit blurry.
Is it possible to use higher resolution image so that the image will not be blurry when zoomed?

As far as I know, images will be scaled in terms of width in Android, but the height will not be scaled, right?

Here's my code for the image displayer :

```
<com.km.parkit.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/overview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/parkinglot" />
```

Comment: Increase you image resolution or use SVG images.

Comment: That's how images are.  If you zoom in, each pixel becomes bigger.  When it becomes too big, its blocky or blurry.  To fix it you need to start with a higher res image, you can't make something a higher resolution than it started out, unless you're in a TV show.

Comment: I used higher res image (from 480x640 to 1440x1920) But it took up the whole screen, is there any method to rescale it inside? Btw I used `android:scaleType="matrix"` as it is required for the TouchImageView function